# sqlsrv_execute returning cursor I cannot return from my method

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, php-7, sqlsrv

We recently upgraded our PHP version from 5 to 7 so I had to chenge the classes used to access our MS SQL database.

I started using sqlsrv and I have a method in a class to execute stored procedures which pretty much does this

```
    <?php
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($db, $sql, $procedure_params);
    if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) { 
          if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null)  
          {  
             foreach( $errors as $error)  
             {  
                echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."\n";  
                echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."\n";  
                echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."\n";  
                die();
             }  
          }  
    }
    // (1) This works, I get all the rows with data, etc... 
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
        print_r($row);
    }
    // (2) Returning the cursos won't work, I cannot fetch it when I return it as a result
    return $stmt;
    ?>
```

Once I execute the stored procedure, I get the result and I can fetch it with no problems (1). However, if I return the cursos as a result of my method / function, when I get the cursos as a result of calling the method, I cannot fetch it, it's like if it was empty. (2)

Any ideas? I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I have been googling for this issue and I cannot see any posts talking about a similar issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, why do you want to return the SQL resource?  If you do that you will have a harder time closing the connection as you will need to do [sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-free-stmt.php) in the function you are passing back to.

Second, and I'm not a PHP expert, but I believe you are using the [sqlsrv_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php) which is mainly made for the one off executions with parameters such as inserts, updates and deletes.  If you want to return a cursor with rows in it you will want to use [sqlsrv_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php).

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer. I tried sqlsrv_query to execute the stored and I couldn't make it work, thought sqlsrv_prepare / execute was the way to go and in fact it worked. The problem arose when wanting to return the results. I could fetch the cursos / assign it to an array and return that, but returning the cursos itself wouldn't work. If I fetch the cursos on the method and then I pass it back and have to fetch the array again, I am doing the same thing twice, that's why I thought it was better to just return the cursos itself. Anyway, I will have another look at sqlsrv_query then..